# Simulation of irrational numbers

Tags: number-theory, physics, matlab, irrational-numbers, simulation

I am trying to write an algorithm that generates two random numbers $x_1$ and $x_2$ in a given range such that their ratio $x_1/x_2$ is an irrational number. I understand that all numbers stored on a computer are rational, so one cannot have a truly irrational number in a simulation. So, is there a way to simulate a situation where the ratio simply has a very long repeat period? How would such an algorithm look like (e.g., in Matlab)?

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

P.S. I am trying to simulate a physical situation where the ratio of the periods of two light waves is not rational (or rather, it has a very long repeat period), so that their combination would not appear to be periodic.

Comment: To get a long period , choose $x_2$ as a large prime (most of them have a "big" order with respect to base $10$ , and therefore give a long period)

Comment: I don't think just getting an irrational ratio is really all what you need in practice. For example if you choose $x_1 = \sqrt{2}$ and $x_2 = \frac{14142}{10000}$ then the ratio is irrational so will not be exactly in phase, however the ratio of these two periods is $1.000002$ which is practically in phase unless you simulate over millions of periods.

Comment: What is the reason you want to do this, why exactly do you need to have a very long repeat period? I'm asking because whatever ratio you choose, rational or not, it would have many *approximate* repeat periods.